# How to get auto generated id for Embedded Id Column in Entity

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

In my Entity **Employee** I have Embedded Id **EmployeeId** contains 2 long properties. I want both properties to generate auto increment id. How can I achieve it.

Employee Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="emp")
public class Employee {

@EmbeddedId
private EmployeeId id;

@Column(name="Emp Name")
private String name;
//Getters and Setters
```

EmployeeId Entity

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Emp Id")
private long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Branch Name")
private long branchName;
//Getters and Setters
```

I also tried to put @Id on Getter to get it work but it does not help.

Config.

```
<hibernate-configuration>  

<session-factory>  
//properties
<mapping class="com.hibernate.model.Employee"/>  
<mapping class="com.hibernate.model.EmployeeId"/>  
</session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code before the column you want.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Comment: please provide proper code so that other can get it easily and also with proper explanation.

Comment: @HarshKanakhara you just need to make those columns as identity. Put above code before property of your entity. The code above mentioned is a in C#.

Comment: are you trying to say to use Hibernate Generated annotation on column ?